# Android Activity não abre

Tags: android, android-activity

Estou fazendo um app de conexão retrofit, mas não estou entendendo pq minha activity não está abrindo.

Meu código:

```
public class CotacaoAlteraActivity  extends AppCompatActivity {
private ListView listView;
ProgressBar pbar;
EditText custoalterar, embalagemalterar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cotacao_altera);

    EnviarAlteracao = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enviaralteracao);
    EnviarAlteracao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });

    String cnpjfornecedor = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_USER, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("PrefCnpj", "");
    String codigoproduto = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_COD, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("PrefCod", "");

    loadCotacaoAlterar(cnpjfornecedor, codigoproduto);

    pbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar4);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView4);

}

public void loadEnviarCotacaoNova(Cotacao cotacao){ //Função POST para enviar os produtos para próxima página pra alterar.

    Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://192.168.25.212:8080/CotacaoWebService/webresources/cotacao/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

    Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

    CotacaoEnviarAlteracaoClient client = retrofit.create(CotacaoEnviarAlteracaoClient.class);
    Call<Cotacao> call = client.reposForUser(cotacao);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Cotacao>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Cotacao> call, Response<Cotacao> response) {
            Cotacao shop = response.body();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Código: " + shop.getCodigoProduto(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Cotacao> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(CotacaoAlteraActivity.this, "Produto inserido na lista", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

public void loadCotacaoAlterar(String buscar, String codigo) {
    Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://192.168.25.212:8080/CotacaoWebService/webresources/cotacao/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

    Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

    CotacaoAlterarGETClient client = retrofit.create(CotacaoAlterarGETClient.class);
    Call<List<Cotacao>> call = client.reposForUser(buscar, codigo);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Cotacao>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Cotacao>> call, Response<List<Cotacao>> response) {
            pbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            List<Cotacao> repos = response.body();
            listView.setAdapter(new CotacaoAlterarAdapter(CotacaoAlteraActivity.this, repos));
            if (listView.getCount() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nenhum produto localizado.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Cotacao>> call, Throwable t) {
            pbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "         Erro ao estabelecer conexão" + "\n"
                    + "            Verifique o host inserido" + "\n"
                    + "Por favor tente novamente mais tarde!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Erro:

> 10-25 15:49:09.696 13243-13243/br.com.cotacaovolpix.cotacaovolpix
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   Process: br.com.cotacaovolpix.cotacaovolpix, PID: 13243
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{br.com.cotacaovolpix.cotacaovolpix/br.com.cotacaovolpix.cotacaovolpix.CotacaoAlteraActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2678)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2743)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1490)
>                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165)
>                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                               at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
>                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
>           Erro está aqui>>>>
>                                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void
>   android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                                               at
>   br.com.cotacaovolpix.cotacaovolpix.CotacaoAlteraActivity.onCreate(CotacaoAlteraActivity.java:39)
>                                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6687)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1140)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2631)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2743) 
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1490) 
>                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165) 
>                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                               at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888) 
>                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)

Comment: O que acontece ? Qual o erro no logcat ?

Comment: Você registrou a Activity no AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Registrei sim, ele só da o erro normal, fecha, pelo que eu vi o erro da quando eu faço o editor dar ok e chamar a função retrofit. Se eu tiro a função do editor de texto ele funciona...

Comment: Dá uma olhada no código dentro do `embalagemalterar.setOnEditorActionListener` você está instanciando  a `Cotacao` e logo depois você começa a definir os valores dessa instancia a ela mesma, sendo que não foi atribuído nenhum valor a estes. por ex: `cotacao.setCodigoProduto(cotacao.getCodigoProduto());` aparentemente isso não faz sentido.

Comment: `embalagemalterar` ou `custoalterar` estão sendo recuperados normalmente? Possuem instância?

Comment: Darlei acontece que mesmo só eu deixando a função do clique ele já da erro, não precisa nem chamar o webservice, nem nada, pode não ter nada dentro da função, mas ele mesmo assim da o erro e fecha o app. Coloquei um botão em vez do setOnEditorActionListener, e mesmo usando o OnClickListener, ele fecha tbm, não sei o que possa ser, mas independente do que eu coloco ele fecha, eu só coloquei a função OnClickListener, sem nada dentro dela, como se quando clicasse no botão não fosse fazer nada, mas mesmo assim ele fecha o app.

Comment: Eu tenho quase 100% de certeza que o erro está na variável ```EnviarAlteracao``` porque o erro é um ```NullPointException``` ,isso quer dizer que a variável tem valor ```null``` ,ou seja ,você esta chamando um método para o ```null``` ,exemplo , ```null.foo()```.

Answer (score 1):

Você está chamando o método `loadCotaçãoAlterar()` e depois chamando o `findViewById()` do `listView` e `progressBar`.... Ai tá o seu erro!

** Solução **

- Chame primeiro os `findViewByIds()` e depois chame os métodos...

Comment: Corte rápido! faca é Tramontina! kkkkk

Answer (score 0):

Um motivo pode ser que você esteja referenciando uma Id de identificação de um TextView ou outro elemento, de forma incorreta na sua Activity.
Se não for esse o caso, tente alterar a ID dos elementos e tente DEBUGAR o seu código com a ajuda de breakPoints, e nos mande a linha em que o erro ocorreu.

Certifique que a sua activity esteja declarada no Manifest da sua aplicação, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
<application...

<activity android:name="fiscale.vc.android.dialog_novidade" android:label="Novidade no Fiscale.vc">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```